# Something wrong when getting the "platform" attribute of EC2 Instances

Tags: linux, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, boto3

I was trying to get the EC2 Instance's Platform name using Python and Boto3. But when I run the script, it only shows the Platform name of Windows Instances as "Windows", whereas every instance running on Linux Platform (Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, CentOS,etc) are showed as "None".
Here are my script:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
filters = [{'Name':'instance-state-name','Values':['running']}]
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters).all()
for inst in instances:
    print inst.id + "-" + str(inst.platform)
```

And the output:

```
i-00dddfd5011ab2993-None
i-0ff7a32debff120de-None
i-018cd715318fc5b2d-None
i-06a84fa0421b7918c-windows
```

Is there any ways that I can get the Platform attribute of Linux Instances?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get the platform and OS from the instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172415/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-platform-and-os-from-the-instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing the exact version of Linux or anything other than null for linux kernel based OS is not possible with AWS SDK or CLI .
There is a way though to solve the issue:

*You can add the tags with all the linux instances and then you can filter out using those tag names.*

Actually AWS SDK and CLI gives you information that are available at the hypervisor level.But these details of which linux images is being used is inside the VM level not at the hypervisor level.

Hope it will help !

Comment: You took this information verbatim from another answer.

Comment: I think i agree for this .. I probably read your answer and it was there in my mind while answering this question. I should definitely not take credit for it. I am going to delete the answer. Sorry for unintentionally taking credit of your work. @helloV

Comment: Not a problem. Don't delete your answer. I was just mentioning it. I do it sometimes unintentionally.